# How to set selectedBackgroundView for UITableViewCell in IB?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I know if I want to change the highlight of a `UITableViewCell`, I need to run code below:

```
self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
self.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

But if I use static cells and build them in Interface Builder, how could I change the color of `selectedBackgroundView` for `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the show, but I stumbled upon this myself and after playing with my storyboard for a few minutes I figured it out.

In my storyboard I had a `UITableViewController` that had a table view containing only static cells. In order to connect a cell's `selectedBackgroundView` outlet to a view, I had to create that view first and it had to reside in the same scene. So i grabbed a new UIView from the library and dragged it to the table view controller's scene. I dropped it between the `First Responder` and the `Exit` outlets, like this:

[image]

When I let it go, it appeared as a separate view outside of the view controller, however it was in the same scene, so I could connect it. Looked like this:

[image]

Then I changed that view's background color and connected the `selectedBackgroundView` outlet of each static cell to that view. Voila! I hope that helps somebody in the future. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Drag a outlet of static cell

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstRowCell: UITableViewCell!
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: firstRowCell.bounds)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    firstRowCell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Or, you can just create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks. This looks straight and useful.

Comment: @zhongdian if it helps,please accpet the answer